# Recommend me a powerful graphics card that will work with my motherboard

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

First question for me on this site, lets see how it goes.
So i have this motherboard.
http://www.asus.com/UK/Motherboards/B150M-A/
Could someone recommend me a powerful graphics card, GTX1070 or something similar that would fit due to the fact my board is mini atx with 4 sata ports in use. What ones are there that will fit?
If someone could find a powerful single case slot g card. Preferably Nvidia based Asus or MSI that would be great.

Comment: What computer case do you have? The top of the line cards can be too big for some cases.

Comment: My computer case is this. http://www.ebuyer.com/722854-aerocool-500-black-midi-tower-gaming-case-with-window-card-reader-acoolcsaero500black?mkwid=s_dc&pcrid=51482418059&pkw=&pmt=&gclid=CMPg37mNoc8CFUI_GwodHPQBXw
accept mine is the white version. There both identical tho. My g card sticks out where the gap is at the front of the case if you look at the picture showing it inside. Giving the g card length all the way to the very front of the PC. It is more my mini atx motherboard that i for see being the problem with a large card.

Comment: The size of your motherboard has nothing to do with the size of the GPU you can connect to it; all motherboards have the exact same PCI-E specifications and supply the maximum of 75W over the PCI-E link (the PSU has to pick up the slack via additional power cables if you want a GPU that needs more than 75W). Because you have a case which accommodates very large cards, the only concern for you, really, is whether your cooling and power supply can handle the card you want to put in. We need to know what PSU you have, and then we can make a good recommendation.

Comment: The psu is a 650watt corsair but not one of there highest end models.
http://www.corsair.com/en-gb/vs-seriestm-vs650-650-watt-power-supply
My case currently has a large fan on front sucking air into it. And one large on the back blowing air out just above where gpu goes. I could add one to the top of the case to blow air down onto CPU and g card... or would it be better to have top one blow outwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the **[Asus Turbo GTX-1070 8gb](http://www.outletpc.com/vb9429-asus-geforce-turbo-gtx1070-8gb.html?utm_source=vb9429-asus-geforce-turbo-gtx1070-8gb&utm_medium=shopping%2Bengine&utm_campaign=pcpartpicker&utm_content=Asus%2B-%2BVideo%20Cards)**. It's the cheapest Asus/MSI 1070 out there, and its blower cooling might actually be of some benefit to you unless you have more fans in your case than the default number it came with.

It is a very long card, but it will fit in your case and one of the two 6/8 PSU cables you have will power it. Furthermore, while it will "cover" 2 of your SATA ports, 4 will be wide open, which is the requirement. I put scare quotes around "cover" because in my experience those ports are still definitely usable, you just have to put the cables in before the card. *Sometimes* you might need to use right-angle SATA cables, but those aren't hard to come by; at least one probably shipped with your motherboard.

TL;DR this WILL work with your current PC setup.

Comment: I just noticed something very interesting. according to official Asus website as pointed to in this PDF of device support for my motherboard. which is here.
http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/B150M-A/B150M-A_Devices_report.pdf
says it supports under graphics card this huge looking thing.
http://www.nvidia.co.uk/gtx-700-graphics-cards/gtx-titan-z/
If it can support that can't it support anything in size wise.

Comment: Of course it does, its an Asus GPU combined with an Asus mobo. But really don't over think this, this GPU would work in 95% of the motherboards out there.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much in the way of powerful single-slot graphics cards out there -- I could find a [GTX 750 Ti](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127836&ignorebbr=1), but that's a mid-range card, and getting somewhat old.

Going the other direction to avoid running in to your SATA cables, Gigabyte makes [short two-slot GTX 1070](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125893&ignorebbr=1) and [GTX 1060](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125903&ignorebbr=1) cards: the card is just barely longer than the PCIe connector.  You may need to move one of your SATA cables from port 3 to port 6, but everything should still work.

And if you're willing to go to extreme effort to get extreme performance, Zotac makes a [GTX 1080 with a low-profile integrated waterblock](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814500406&ignorebbr=1).  You'll need to set up a watercooling system to go with it, though.

Comment: Thanks sata 3 could be moved. Also i am very interested in that small Gigabyte gtx1070 because that is pretty much the card i wanted. I'll have a look on the sites i buy components from for it later.
being smaller would it be slower or anything than the normal full sized GTX1070s? (not counting the factory overclocked ones of coarse)

Comment: The listed specs for the Gigabyte GTX 1070 are the same or slightly above those listed by NVidia.

Comment: Found it too on a site that ships to me because I'm from the UK newegg don't ship here :P
http://www.ebuyer.com/757031-gigabyte-geforce-gtx-1070-mini-itx-oc-8gb-gddr5-dual-link-dvi-d-hdmi-gv-n1070ixoc-8gd?mkwid=s_dc&pcrid=51482416259&pkw=&pmt=&gclid=COSMysaooc8CFUgW0woddxoIMQ

Comment: Thought i would point out that the card in pc currently is longer than that gtx 1070 but not double sized as in doesn't take up two rear case ports. It is a gtx960 4gb. I cheeped out at the time on g card and what i regret most looking back is not getting a full sized motherboard. Would be very annoying to change motherboard. But the fact that my current g card is bigger than that gtx1070 in length means i am most certainly safe if i got that one :)

Comment: Because it is smaller, it will heat up faster and cool down more slowly. That being said, I am given to understand that the 1070 is not a hot card, so it might not be a problem.